# Change Location of JSP file

Tags: html, jsp

I want to change location of JSP file without click any button.
I know that if I add event for a button it's look like:
onclick="location.href='page2.jsp'"

how can I change the page in IF statement ?

```
if(....){
//change JSP page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`response.sendRedirect(String location)`

In the if statement.